# How to get an editable text box to work on a canvas (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input-field

I am very new to Unity, but I am tearing my hair out trying to do this incredibly simple thing. I am trying to:

1. place a text field on a canvas
2. be able to initialise it with a number (eg 234)
3. be able to select / overtype etc that with a new text value (eg 678)
4. read it back at a later date

Shouldn't be hard.

With most UI systems, you have a type of text box control you can write to, edit, read from, and get onChange() notifications of one sort or another. Unity appears to have split the output display field (type Text) from the input field (type InputField), and despite reading the docs and looking a stuff I cannot just work out how to do it.

The input field has a sub-component of type Text, but nothing appears to be displayed there. It seems you need an extra Text field, and to update it onChange() from the InputField. Fine, that works, but (a) if they are co-located, can no longer get focus on the input field to type anything, and (b) anyway you cannot select any text.

How on earth is one supposed to do this?

Comment: for example:
`public InputField banana;

void Start()
{
    banana.text = "234";
    banana.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { BananaChanged(); });
}

public void BananaChanged()
{
    Debug.Log(banana.text); //after change
}
`
Just create UI=>InputField and drag this gameobject into component's field `banana`.
Is that what you want?

Comment: and to answer your last question: don't use external Text. Text within InputField works but do not call to it directly but use InputField component to change Text Component.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll try it. Got it to work now but only with external Text, so I'll try what you say.